# Systemd target file starts eventhough the After= service is not started

Tags: ubuntu, prometheus, systemd, prometheus-node-exporter

Okay, first of all, I want to accomplish that a systemd service does not get garbage collected, if it is stopped and not enabled by default.
I need this because of a [current problem with the node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/issues/1082)  from [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) for monitoring purposes.

I did already accomplish my goal but I am not sure why it does work and if there are possible side effects.

So as an example I installed ntp on my Ubuntu 18.03, disabled the service and stopped it. Now I wanted my node exporter to show me, that ntp.service is inactive, but ntp get's garbage collected by systemd. I read that this can be prevented by using, in this case, ntp as dependency somewhere. Using `Wants=` does not help, since this would result in a restart of my ntp, if my dependent service restarts. So I experimented a bit and I created a test.target file like this:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/test.target
[Unit]
Description=Testing purpose
After=ntp.service

[Install]
WantedBy=Multi-user.target
```

I enabled the service and started it with ntp disabled and stopped. Now that is my actual Question. My test.target file does get enabled and starts without a problem, even though ntp.service is not running. Interestingly it also does what I want, ntp does not get garbage collected, even though it is disabled and stopped.

So I really would like to know why this works, why does the `After=` get's ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `After=` is not being ignored, it is causing `systemd` to load the unit (if it isn't already loaded) and also preventing the garbage collection.
The `After=` doesn't mean it will start `ntp.service`, for that you should use `Requires=`.

Check [Unit Garbage Collection](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit%20Garbage%20Collection), [Requires](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=), and [After](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=).